# 3D Analyst tools (TIN)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, tin

I have created an elevation contour (topography) with TIN using a spreadsheet of coordinates and elevations of some points. now I want to find the elevation of a new point with these contours. how can I do that ?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArcToolbox>3D Features>Functional Surface>Interpolate Shape. Use your Tin and the point layer as your inputs... name an output file... contours not necessary for this.